# Why I need to reset a variable?

Tags: c#, variables, reset

What's the differences if I reset the variable or not? For example

```
public static int Digits(int f)        
{
    int result = 0;
    while (f != 0)
    {
        result += f % 10;
        f /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here `int result = 0` I've reset the variable, why do I need to do this and what's happens if i won't do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this homework? Seems like you could at least try it out to see what happens.

Comment: Try to not do that and see.

Comment: That's called initializing a variable, not "resetting" it.

Comment: You aren't "resetting" a variable. You are declaring and instantiating a variable within the scope of the method which will cease to exist once the method returns.

Comment: @I'L'L I didn't know that, thx

Comment: @Abion47 ok, but why i need to initialize the variable?

Comment: Well doing `int result;` declares it. Doing `int result = 0;` initializes it. Read more about the two here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming)

Comment: [Here is the output for the program](https://ideone.com/2MlXDh) this will show you the behavior of the program. Try taking away `int result = 0`, and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it because the C# compiler requires you to before it allows you to read from the variable. If you don't, then the compiler produces an error instead of an executable program.

The reason the compiler requires this stems from the fact that the variable must have *some* value when it is used (that is, the memory location that holds the value of this variable is comprised of a number of bytes that must necessarily have *some* value), so the choice is not really between "initializing the variable or not"; it is between knowing what value the variable has or not.

Since making computations with a variable that has a completely unknown and unpredictable value does not generally produce useful results, the compiler forces you to be explicit in order to prevent accidental mistakes. Languages where the compiler is not required to do this (e.g. C and C++) are notorious for allowing programmers to write bugs of exactly this type.

It's interesting to note that there are other ways the compiler could have achieved the same objective, e.g. by implicitly initializing the value to the default for the data type (for integers, that would be zero) -- and indeed, it does do exactly this with class fields. The decision depends on the reasoning of the language designers.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand that.. If I will use the variable without setting an value, so I will get an error. 
you clarified to me a few things.

Comment: My guess is that C# was designed in the way it was to eliminate ambiguity. By forcing the programmer to instantiate the variable before it can be used, there's no question as to what the value of that variable will be. Even assigning it a default value will force people to find out what that default value *is*.

Comment: @Abion47 Without a doubt, you right.